# Why does this non-local function only work when arguments are provided?

Tags: r, function

I have a function that is defined outside of the scope of, and is used by, a second function. Consider:

```r
my_fun <- function(){
  return( x + 1 )
}

my_big_fun <- function(N, start){
  
  res <- numeric(N)
  res[1] <- start
  
  for(i in 2:N){
    x <- res[i-1]
    res[i] <- my_fun()
  }
  
  res
}

my_big_fun(N = 10, start = 1)
```

I would imagine that this routine would output the sequence of numbers 1:N, but instead I get:

```r
[1]  1 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

It works, however, if I don't wrap the code in `my_big_fun`.

And, if I define `my_fun` to take an argument `x` like:

```r
my_fun2 <- function(x){
  return( x + 1 )
}

my_big_fun_2 <- function(N, start){
  
  res <- numeric(N)
  res[1] <- start
  
  for(i in 2:N){
    x <- res[i-1]
    res[i] <- my_fun2(x)
  }
  
  res
}

my_big_fun_2(N = 10, start = 1)
```

I get the desired output `[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10`

I don't quite know why the first pass doesn't work as desired: I would have thought that `my_fun()` should access the local `x` variable defined within `my_big_fun`.

Any pointers?

Comment: If a function refers to an object which is not defined in the function it looks into the environment in which the function ws *defined*, not the caller.

Comment: Thanks. Ignore my previous comment (deleted now) -- I see that x must have been set to 9 in my global environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If x is not globally defined then the function will not work at all. If x is already defined globally (and I think it is set to 9 in your case), the function will return x+1 every time. The assignment inside my_big_func has no influence because it cannot overwrite a global variable. The reason the first position of res is 1 is because you explicitly set it to 'start'.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense to me now.